# OpenGL glCallLists Drawing Incorrect Characters On Windows 7

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-7

I have an old application written in Visual C++ 6. Part of this app is drawing text into a bitmap. This works fine on Windows XP but when the same code is run on Windows 7 all the text is shifted by one place in the ASCII table.

For example, `"Category"` becomes `"B'sdfnqx"`.

Any ideas what is causing this and how to fix it?

Edit: Sorry but the above is slightly incorrect. When I saw the DrawText function in the code I assumed it was the GDI function. When I step into it, it turns out that the author has created their own `DrawText` function which is using `OpenGL`. I don't know any `OpenGL` so this has now got out of hand. It calls `glCallLists` which passes the text (stored in a `CString`) into this function.

Full class code below. Note: it is the glCallLists function in the DrawText function causing the problem.

```
OGLFontClass::OGLFontClass()
{
    m_id = -1;
}

OGLFontClass::~OGLFontClass()
{
    Clear();
}

void OGLFontClass::Clear()
{
    if( m_id != -1 )
    {
        glDeleteLists(m_id,255);
        m_id = -1;
    }
}

void OGLFontClass::Initialise(CString fontname, int size, HDC hDC)
{
    m_HDC = hDC;
    m_id = glGenLists(255);
    ::DeleteObject( m_FONT );

    m_FONT = CreateFont(    -size,              // Height Of Font ( NEW )
                            0,              // Width Of Font
                            0,              // Angle Of Escapement
                            0,              // Orientation Angle
                            FW_NORMAL,          // Font Weight
                            FALSE,              // Italic
                            FALSE,              // Underline
                            FALSE,              // Strikeout
                            ANSI_CHARSET,           // Character Set Identifier
                            OUT_TT_PRECIS,          // Output Precision
                            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // Clipping Precision
                            ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,        // Output Quality
                            FF_DONTCARE|DEFAULT_PITCH,  // Family And Pitch
                            fontname);          // Font Name

    HFONT oldfont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, m_FONT);       // Selects The Font We Want
    wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 0, 255, m_id );          // Builds 96 Characters Starting At Character 32
    ::SelectObject( hDC, oldfont );
}

void OGLFontClass::DrawText( float x, float y, CString str )
{
    glRasterPos3f(x,y, 0);

    glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
        glListBase(m_id);
        glCallLists(str.GetLength(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, str.GetBuffer(0));
    glPopAttrib();
}

void OGLFontClass::DrawText(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, CString text)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();// Reset The View

    HWND hWnd = ::WindowFromDC(wglGetCurrentDC() );

    RECT rc;
    ::GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );

    int CX = rc.right;//::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    int CY = rc.bottom;//::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );

    gluOrtho2D (0,::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(r,g,b);  

    glRasterPos2d( x, y );   // had to do this to get the text to line up where i want it

    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);      // Pushes The Display List Bits     ( NEW )
    glListBase(m_id);               // Sets The Base Character to 32    ( NEW )

    unsigned char* szTemp = new unsigned char[text.GetLength()+1];
    strcpy((char*)szTemp, text);

    glCallLists(strlen((char*)szTemp), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, szTemp);   // Draws The Display List Text  ( NEW )

    delete[] szTemp;

    glPopAttrib();                      // Pops The Display List Bits   ( NEW )

    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void OGLFontClass::DrawRightText( int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, CString text )
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();// Reset The View

    HWND hWnd = ::WindowFromDC(wglGetCurrentDC() );

    RECT rc;
    ::GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );

    float CX = (float)::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
    float CY = (float)::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );
    float fMultiplier = CX / CY;

    gluOrtho2D (0,::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    int nPos = x;

    glColor3ub(r,g,b);  
    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);      // Pushes The Display List Bits     ( NEW )

    glListBase(m_id);               // Sets The Base Character to 32    ( NEW )

    for( int i = text.GetLength() - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        CString sChar = text.GetAt(i);

        glRasterPos2d(nPos,y);   // had to do this to get the text to line up where i want it
        glCallLists(1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sChar);    // Draws The Display List Text  ( NEW )

        if ( i > 0 )
        {
            CString sNextChar = text.GetAt(i-1);

            SIZE szWidth = GetTextExtent(sNextChar);
            szWidth.cx += 1;
            szWidth.cx *= fMultiplier;
            szWidth.cx += 1;

            nPos -= szWidth.cx;
        }
    }

    //glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);    // Draws The Display List Text  ( NEW )

    glPopAttrib();                      // Pops The Display List Bits   ( NEW )

    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

CSize OGLFontClass::GetTextExtent(CString text, float fFactor)
{
    SIZE sz;
    HFONT oldfont = (HFONT) SelectObject(m_HDC, m_FONT);
    GetTextExtentPoint32(m_HDC,text,strlen(text),&sz);

    SelectObject(m_HDC, oldfont);

    sz.cx *= 0.2;
    sz.cy *= 0.2;

    return sz;
}
```

Now I don't know openGL at all but I'm assuming that as `glCallLists` just reinterprets the string as a byte array there is something going wrong in this between Windows XP and Windows 7. Perhaps a unicode issue or something? 32-bit Windows OS versus 64-bit OS maybe?

Does this now show up a more obvious problem?

Comment: What a gerat question.  I want to know the answer myself, even though it doesn't affect me :-).

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I'll get a great answer ;)

Comment: Surely, this issue would be independent of the font used.

Comment: @Sachin: no, it the lowest level problem seems to be incorrect indexing (off by one) into the font's glyphs, so the font technology may very well be relevant. a complete example would be even nicer than knowing which font.

Comment: Also, just to add to this, I have tried running the app with all the different compatibility options but it makes no difference.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for enlightening me on that - I had no idea.

Comment: Can you try it with another font? Maybe the font file is corrupted. And can you post some example code so we can try and replicate?

Comment: I have now updated the original post as it turns out this is not a GDI issue and actually a OpenGL issue. Author of the code had created a function called DrawText which I just assumed was the GDI call. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would guess that the base list number passed to glCallLists is hard-coded somewhere instead of using the value returned from glGenLists. And that glGenLists is returning different values on your different PCs. You may want to check that.

Comment: There is no call in the function to glGenLists. I'll see where it is called. I've updated the original post with the function code. As mentioned before, this code works on WinXP (32bit) but not Win7 (64-bit)

Comment: glGenLists is called with the value 255 (the 255 is hardcoded). The value returned from glGenLists is stored in a member variable which is then used for glCallLists so this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Original post updated with full class code as from previous comments I now believe that the error code may be beyond the actual function that draws the text.

Comment: I have now debugged this on both a XP and Win7 machine and glGenLists returns the same value on both. It is not hard coded. So it looks like it is something else. Does anyone have any ideas as this desperately needs to be fixed now.

Comment: Does the problem occur only with `DrawText`, only with `DrawRightText`, or with both?

Comment: DrawRightText isn't used anywhere so I'm not sure. Really need a solution to this or I face having to rewrite a lot of code to remove all the OpenGL stuff.

Comment: From what I can see, the code is mostly correct as far as the bitmap font / list base / call list stuff goes, though I would use 256 characters rather than 255 (don't forget zero!), and there are some (unrelated) things that are kind of "not pretty". You're calling `glCallLists` with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` when you want `GL_BYTE`. This **will** break non-ASCII text (though it _should not_ cause the error you are seeing). Unconditionally calling `::DeleteObject(m_FONT)` when `m_FONT` is not initialized to e.g. `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in the constructor [...]

Comment: [...] , i.e. you're deleting a "random" handle value. This _probably_ has no effect, but you really don't know... you _might_ in fact accidentially delete an existing GDI handle. `DrawRightText` would be much clearer code (and faster, and less code to debug!)  if it was implemented as `DrawText(x - GetTextExtent(...), ...);`.

Comment: It's not my code and I agree it isn't the best but none of those things are making any difference. What makes some difference is commenting out the glpushattrib and glpopattrib calls. Then some lines of text display correctly and some don't. I don't know OpenGL at all so I'm stabbing in the dark here.

Comment: The push/pop is kind of "not necessary" as long as you don't use display lists anywhere else, or as long as you always remember to set the list base (which is better anyway, using the stack is discouraged). It should make no difference whether or not you have the push/pop in your example, all you do is "save current state, set state to defined value, use state, restore saved state". Without the push/pop, it's just "set state to defined value, use state"

Comment: You say it shouldn't make any difference but as I said it most definitely does make a big difference. Still not 100% though.

Comment: @Damon: `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is correct, you don't want to use values less than the `glListBase` for extended-ASCII characters.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh my, you're right... seems I wasn't quite at myself when writing that one, got it exactly the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

This line clearly doesn't do what its comment says:

```
wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 0, 255, m_id );          // Builds 96 Characters Starting At Character 32
```

Nor does this:

```
glListBase(m_id);               // Sets The Base Character to 32    ( NEW )
```

Somehow, your `m_id` variable is off by one from what it should be.  Replace this line by

```
glListBase(m_id+1);
```

both places it occurs, and all should be well on Windows 7.  But XP will break.

A better fix would be to actually generate only the printable characters, as the accompanying comments suggest.  Then you'll not have issues if one of the computers is missing a non-printing character.

Comment: I know. I think the person who wrote this code got it off the internet and the changed the values without changing the comments. As I've said this isn't my code. The ids are fine. They are the correct values. I checked and double checked this.

Comment: @Jonnster: What happens if you do `wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 'a', 26, m_id+'a' );` after the existing `wglUseFontBitmaps`?  Have you tried printing `m_id` to the console every time it's used?  Perhaps you have an invalid `this` pointer, resulting in a corrupted copy of `m_id` being used.

Comment: m_id is always valid and always the correct value. I tried changing it to m_id+1 and exactly the same characters are printed. This was odd but then I don't know OpenGL so nothing should surprise me ;)

Comment: @Jonnster: For starters, which of the two `DrawText` functions is behaving badly?

Comment: The longer DrawText function. I added the wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 'a', 26, m_id+'a' ); code and it still prints the same characters as before.

Comment: @Jonnster: Then I would highly recommend setting up a minimal reproduction.  One window, one context, one font loaded into display lists, one `glCallLists` call.  For that matter, any difference between calling individual display lists explicitly vs using `glCallLists` to emit a whole sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, as this is what I was suspecting.  I actually suspect that it is a UNICODE thing.  I noticed this years ago when I tried to move to a later version fo Visual C++.  Problem is most likely that the compiler beyond 2003 automatically typedefs CStrings to wchar_t.  Take a look at the linked item below.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/fa43f4aa-1822-405e-a95f-9b6377b64352

Comment: The code is not being recompiled in a newer compiler. It's the same executable that runs fine on XP not working on Win7. It does not seem to be anything to do with unicode. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually it still could be, considering that all of the underlying DLLs have most likely changed between XP and 7. This is fairly obvious considering that the output functionality is changing simply by changing the operating system you are running on WITHOUT a re-compile.  There is a string copy going on in your DrawText routine.

Comment: Forcing the same DLLs makes no difference. Actually the original code didn't have that string copy. It was just me messing around with the code and I forgot to put it back before I posted here. So no the string copy has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the shorter version of the DrawText routine (without the r,g,b) function properly?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug after changing from XP to Windows 7.
If you use the native opengl32.dll driver from windows (without drivers from your grahpicscard, like under RDP) then you have a problem with glCallLists() between glNewList/glEndList.

see Lession 13 von NeHe  http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002
and change glPrint() to write a line shifted by one place in the ASCII table and a second correct line. (use Windows 7 with RDP Screen)

```
GLvoid glPrint(const char *fmt, ...)                    // Custom GL "Print" Routine
{
    char        text[256];                              // Holds Our String
    va_list     ap;                                     // Pointer To List Of Arguments

    if (fmt == NULL)                                    // If There's No Text
        return;                                         // Do Nothing

    va_start(ap, fmt);                                  // Parses The String For Variables
        vsprintf_s(text, fmt, ap);                      // And Converts Symbols To Actual Numbers
    va_end(ap);                                         // Results Are Stored In Text

    //first text line
    glRasterPos2f(-0.8f, 0);
    GLuint List1 = glGenLists (1);
    glNewList(List1, GL_COMPILE);
      glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);                            // Pushes The Display List Bits
      glListBase(base1);                                // Sets The Base Character to 32
      glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);    // Draws The Display List Text
      glPopAttrib();                                        // Pops The Display List Bits
    glEndList();
    glCallList(List1);

    //second text line
    glRasterPos2f(-0.8f, -0.2f);
    glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);                          // Pushes The Display List Bits
    glListBase(base1);                              // Sets The Base Character
    glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);  // Draws The Display List Text
    glPopAttrib();                                      // Pops The Display List Bits

}
```

An indication of this trouble:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glNewList.xml
glCallList and glCallLists can be entered into display lists.
Commands in the display list or lists executed by glCallList  or glCallLists are not included in the display list being created, even if the list creation mode is GL_COMPILE_AND_EXECUTE.

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine on Windows XP but when the same code is run on
>   Windows 7 all the text is shifted by one place in the ASCII table.

the opengl32.dll from windows 7 and windows 8 have trouble with a display list call between  glNewList/glEndList

see answer with sample "glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);"

**my solution:**

simple copy the "old" opengl32.dll from XP (windows\system32) to your program folder